# Application Error, Faulting Module name: KERNELBASE.DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, crash, application-error

I have an application written in .Net Framework 3.5. It is a service which is running on a Windows Server 2003 R2. The application has a global Exception-Handling included an all Exceptions which occure outside a try-catch are catched by this global Exception-Handling (done with AppDomain.UnhandledException).

Anyway it happens that the Application crashs. After the crash I can see a "Application Error" in Event Viewer of Windows. It tells me:

```
Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.DLL, version 6.3.9600.18007
Exception code: 0xe06d7363
```

This code is within frmMain_Load:

```
 AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ThreadExceptionHandler
 AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledExceptionHandler
```

This is the handling of unhandled exceptions:

```
   Private Shared Sub ThreadExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)

    HandleException(e.Exception, False)

End Sub

Private Shared Sub UnhandledExceptionHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)

    HandleException(CType(e.ExceptionObject, Exception), e.IsTerminating)

End Sub

Private Shared Sub HandleException(ByVal p_Exception As Exception, ByVal p_Kill As Boolean)

    Try
        ERROR_LOG.AddFatalError(New Exception("Unbehandelte Ausnahme." & If(p_Kill, " Die Anwendung wird beendet.", ""), p_Exception))
    Catch
    End Try
    If p_Kill Then System.Environment.Exit(-1)

End Sub
```

Update 1) I inserted uncaught exceptions at different places in my code, but every time the exception gets handled. This is on my development-environment. Maybe, I have to test this on the server.

What problem do I have? How can I analyze this error?
Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the `UnhandledException` event during application startup or form load? If during form load, try subscribing to it during startup instead via the [**`Startup` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup(v=vs.110).aspx). See [**this**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2bys999(v=vs.100).aspx) for more info.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, you are right, I am subscribing it in form load. The button "view application events" is not enabled, because I am running a service, which launchs a hidden Form. Why should I activate unhandled-exceptionhandling outside my form?

Comment: Because if the error is thrown before you subscribe to the event you won't be able to catch it.

Comment: I definitely subscribe before the error occurs. I subscribe at the start of the application and the error occurs hours later.

Comment: Hmmh, I'm afraid I don't know much more then...